# Implementing selection page that each selection leads to different options in android

Tags: android, listview

You know many apps have the selection page where each option leads to different options? For example, sat that there is a list view with options A and B, and selecting A gives a list view with options C and D, but selecting B gives another list view with options E and F, and so forth.

How is this usually implemented in Android? A straightforward implementation would be having an activity for each selection and starting the corresponding activities with a switch or if statements. This will work but I bet it is inefficient and is not a recommended way.

What is this type of technique/schematic/solution called? What is it that I should look into? Thanks.

Comment: If you have seen this in any of the apps its better to post the screen shot, so We ll get actual picture of your requirement

Comment: @Moulesh I will do so once I see it again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You Can use Expandable List View For this

[expandable list view](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

You can follow the above link to solve your problem.

Comment: This isn't actually what I meant. I will revisit and provide an actual screenshot of this functionality once I find it, thanks!